# Globally access JSON object read from local file using asynchronous XMLHttpRequest() with anonymous callback function?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I am attempting to manipulate data loaded from a local JSON file using [this method](http://codepen.io/KryptoniteDove/blog/load-json-file-locally-using-pure-javascript) (no jQuery) but seem not to be able to access the object on a global scope:

```
 var actual_JSON;

 function loadJSON(callback) {   
    var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
    xobj.open('GET', 'my_data.json', true);
    xobj.onreadystatechange = function () {
          if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {
            callback(xobj.responseText);
          }
      };
    xobj.send(null);  
 }
```

The function then is called once the document is loaded, using an anonymous function as follows:

```
function loaded(e) {

    loadJSON( function(response) {
            actual_JSON = JSON.parse(response);
            console.log(actual_JSON); // Object {...}
        }
    );
    console.log(actual_JSON); // undefined
};

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", loaded, false);
```

Unfortunately I don't fully understand the concept of closures yet and whether/how it affects the scope of `actual_JSON`. It seems to be defined only inside the anonymous function passed to `loadJSON()` as callback for `XMLHttpRequest()`, although I declare it globally.

Comment: it is in global scope, eventually, it's more a matter of timing than scope. you need to wait for callback to fire before the global is assigned. if you `console.log(actual_JSON )` from the console after running, you can see the global.

Comment: You are right, using the console, I can see that actual_JSON is defined.

Comment: While http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call is related, I disagree with it being a duplicate, as my question already uses a callback. The solution to my problem would be to run dependant code from inside the callback or to block interaction until the global object has been defined.

Answer (score -1):

Try to define `actual_JSON` in outer scope:

```
function loaded(e) {
    var actual_JSON;
    loadJSON( function(response) {
            actual_JSON = JSON.parse(response);
            console.log(actual_JSON); // Object {...}
        }
    );
    console.log(actual_JSON); // undefined
};

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", loaded, false);
```

This variable was defined in `function(response)` scope and it was not visible in `loaded(e)` scope.

Comment: `actual_JSON` is defined globally, at the very top of question's code

Comment: Thanks and sorry, but this is incorrect and apparently untested.